# functioning with aplu5, java's library

Tags: java

i'm using the import **ch.aplu.turtle.*** from aplu5 library and i would set the dimension of the frame which contains the turtle (called Java Turtle Playground) and set also the start position of the turtle but I couldn't find any information about that ...

*Could someone help me?*

[image: turtle playground]
<sub>(source: [legorobotik.ch](http://www.legorobotik.ch/turtle/bilder/tu1.png))</sub>

Answer (score 1):

You can find a detailed documentation for future research here:  http://www.aplu.ch/classdoc/turtle/index.html

You can set the start point of the Turtle with the **setPos(double x, double y)** methode.

```
    Turtle turtleOne = new Turtle(Color.MAGENTA);
    Turtle turtleTwo = new Turtle(turtleOne, Color.blue);
    Turtle turtleThree = new Turtle(turtleTwo, Color.green);
    Turtle turtleFour = new Turtle(turtleTwo, Color.black);

    turtleOne.setPos(-100, 0);
    turtleTwo.setPos(100, 0);
    turtleThree.setPos(0, 150);
    turtleFour.setPos(0, -150);
```

[setPos example picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kBkAq.png)

The best solution is to just set the TurtleFrame size. 
 **public TurtleFrame(java.lang.String title, int width, int height)**

```
    TurtleFrame myTurtleframe = new TurtleFrame("Title", 500, 500);
    Turtle myTurtle = new Turtle(myTurtleframe);
```

If you want to change the Playground dimensions anyway: 
 **public Playground(java.awt.Dimension size)**

```
Playground myPlayground = new Playground(new Dimension(500,500));
```

size.width and size.height should be even positive integers. The size determines the span of turtle coordinates (-width/2 .. width/2, -height/2 .. height/2) and and the window size in pixels is (m+1) x (n+1).